# Como puedo colocar un input de solo lectura en angular usando formulario reactivos?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

Como puedo colocar un input de solo lectura en angular usando formulario reactivos sin tener que agregar `readonly` en el html?

Answer (score 0):

Solo necesitas agregar .disable() en el campo que necesitas que sea de "solo lectura"

```
this.myForm.controls['input1'].disable();
```

Comment: Le agregaría esta información sobre cómo obtener el valor del input https://stackoverflow.com/a/54920060/8179980

Answer (score 0):

agregar de esta forma y lo puedes modificar desde el componente sin necesidad de agregar en html.

```
this.myForm.get('input1').disable({ onlySelf: true });
```